# py2exe deal global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made an exe file by using py2exe (python2).

My partial code of hello.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from new_ui import *
.....
global dir_name 
dir_name = dir_name.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
...
```

and new_ui.py has dir_name variable.

When I start my main.py, it works. But if I complie my code into .exe file, it doesn't work. Here's my setup.py files.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, glob

setup(
     console=[
         {'script':'hello.py','icon_resources':[(1, 'cal.ico')]}
         ], 
     data_files=[ ('C:\\Users\\Ko\\Desktop\\python exe\\'+u'가계부\\'+'imageformats',glob.glob('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt4\\plugins\\imageformats\\*.*')) ],
     options = {'py2exe': {
         'bundle_files':3,
         'dist_dir':'C:\\Users\\Ko\\Desktop\\python exe\\'+u'가계부',
         'includes': ['sip','PyQt4.QtNetwork','new_ui'], 
         "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll","w9xpopen.exe"] 
         }},
     zipfile = None
     )
```

All I can see is this error message.

> global name 'dir_name' is not defined

What should I do?

Comment: main.py is hello.py

Comment: What do you want to do? if just to make `new_ui.py.dir_name` a global variable, you should assign it to a global scope variable: `dir_name = py.dir_name`

Comment: I changed source like

Comment: from new_ui import *; import new_ui; and assign variable like dir_name = new_ui.dir_name.encode(sys.stdout.encoding); It works. But It's not working when I made this to py2exe. error message : module object has no attribute 'dir_name'